# How to have an entire page scrollable in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Hi i'm trying to learn Flutter since several days ago, but i'm facing an issue that i can't fix.
I created one page (HomeScreen) and in that page i insert 2 components (villaGrid and villaTile).

My villaTile component is a listView with an horizontal scroll direction.
My villaGrid component is a gridView.

Currently my page is not scrollable, my gridView component is vertically scrollable but i don't want that.
I want to be able to scroll only the page not the villaGrid component to see the other elements.

This is my HomeScreen code :

```
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 40),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  const Text(
                    "Booking",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 32,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.yellowAccent[700],
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                    ),
                    child: const Icon(
                      Icons.add,
                      size: 32,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 30,
              child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: categoryType.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return CategoryType(
                    categoryType: categoryType[index][0],
                    isSelected: categoryType[index][1],
                    onTap: () {
                      categoryTypeSelected(index);
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            VillaTile(),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            VillaGrid(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

This is my VillaGrid component code :

```
Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
      child: Expanded(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  const Text(
                    'Popular stays',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                    ),
                    child: const Icon(
                      Icons.filter_list,
                      size: 18,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                height: 300,
                child: GridView.builder(
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                  ),
                  itemCount: villas.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    Villa villa = villas[index];
                    return Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      // width: 240,
                      child: Stack(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow(
                                  color: Colors.black26,
                                  offset: Offset(0, 2),
                                  blurRadius: 6,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            child: ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              child: Image(
                                width: 150,
                                height: 220,
                                image: AssetImage(villa.imagePath),
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            width: 150,
                            height: 220,
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    width: 100,
                                    child: Stack(
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                          villa.name,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              // color: Colors.white,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                              foreground: Paint()
                                                ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
                                                ..strokeWidth = 2
                                                ..color = Colors.black),
                                        ),
                                        Text(
                                          villa.name,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        '\$${villa.price.toString()}',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontSize: 24,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        'per night',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                            top: 0,
                            right: 0,
                            child: Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.yellowAccent[700],
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(12),
                                ),
                              ),
                              child: Text(
                                villa.rating.toString(),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

This is my VilaTile component code :

```
Container(
      height: 180,
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: VillaCategories.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          VillaCategory villaCategory = VillaCategories[index];
          return Container(
            width: 350,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 20,
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 180,
                        child: Text(
                          villaCategory.title,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 18,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const Text(
                        " 3 offers",
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 8),
                  Text(
                    villaCategory.date,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[400]),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 8),
                  Column(
                    children: villaCategory.benefits
                        .map((benefit) => Container(
                              width: 300,
                              child: Wrap(
                                spacing: 8,
                                runSpacing: 8,
                                children: benefit.name
                                    .asMap()
                                    .entries
                                    .map(
                                      (entry) => Container(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: getColor(entry.key),
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                        ),
                                        child: Text(
                                          entry.value,
                                          style: const TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                    .toList(),
                              ),
                            ))
                        .toList(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
```

I try using Listview widget at the top of the parent file (Homescreen)
I try to change ListView with a Column widget and add SingleChildScrollView widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I did to achieve this is turning ListView in HomeScreen to [CustomScrollView](https://blog.logrocket.com/building-custom-flutter-scrollview/#:%7E:text=CustomScrollView%20is%20a%20widget%20that,%2C%20grids%2C%20and%20expanding%20headers.) which supplies slivers directly to create various scrolling effects.

Code:

```
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
      body: SafeArea(
          child: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverPadding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 40),
            sliver: SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  const Text(
                    "Booking",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 32,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.yellowAccent[700],
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                    ),
                    child: const Icon(
                      Icons.add,
                      size: 32,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 30,
              child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: categoryType.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    width: 400,
                    child: Text(categoryType[index].categoryType),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: const SizedBox(height: 20),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: VillaTile(),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: const SizedBox(height: 20),
          ),
          SliverFillRemaining(
            child: VillaGrid(),
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
```

and in VillaGrid container with a height of 300 which wraps the Expanded->GrideView is removed and GridView scroll physics is set to NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() to stop it from scrolling.

Code:

```
Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              const Text(
                'Popular stays',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                ),
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.filter_list,
                  size: 18,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: GridView.builder(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                mainAxisSpacing: 10,
              ),
              itemCount: villa.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                Villa villaItem = villa[index];
                return Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  // width: 240,
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.black26,
                              offset: Offset(0, 2),
                              blurRadius: 6,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          child: Image(
                            width: 150,
                            height: 220,
                            image: AssetImage(villaItem.imagePath),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: 150,
                        height: 220,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                width: 100,
                                child: Stack(
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      villaItem.name,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          // color: Colors.white,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                          foreground: Paint()
                                            ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
                                            ..strokeWidth = 2
                                            ..color = Colors.black),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      villaItem.name,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Column(
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    '\$${villaItem.price.toString()}',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 24,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    'per night',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                        top: 0,
                        right: 0,
                        child: Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.yellowAccent[700],
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(12),
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: Text(
                            villaItem.rating.toString(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: welcome! keep fluttering